# Stored field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

In the documentation,  some types,  such as numbers and dates,  it specifies that store defaults to no. But that the field can still be retrieved from the json.

Its confusing. Does this mean _source?

Is there a way to not store a field at all,  and just have it indexed and searchable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the field types are stored by default. Only the [`_source`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/source-field/) field is. That means you can always get back what you sent to the search engine. Even if you ask for specific fields, elasticsearch is going to parse the `_source` field for you and give you back those fields.

You can disable the `_source` if you want but then you could only retrieve the fields that you explicitly stored, according to your mapping.

Comment: so, if _source is enabled. setting store=no in a specific field is meaningless?

Comment: You might want to do that in some cases but I wouldn't do it "by default". With the _source you can always retrieve the whole source anyway, that's all you need.