# elasticsearch does not return all hits when field is an object

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm confused about the results given by Elasticsearch

I use a simple query for testing,

```
body: {
   size: 100,
   from: 0,
   query: { match_all: {} },
   fields: ["object"]    <--- this is an object

}
```

Pretty straight forward

I get hits. `hits.total = 141380`

But the `hits.hits.length = 49`

If I increase `size` to `1000`, I get `hits.hits.length = 129`

while the hits.total is still `hits.total = 141380`

if I don't use `fields`, I get all docs, and in a readable format, but if i specify fields i get an array of array of objects of key arrays (yes complicated format for a search result!)

Can someone explain why it is different when using fields? I would expect the object with only the fields I requested.

Comment: is it possible that some of your documents don't have the `object` field? If out of 100 matching documents, only 49 have the `object` field, that would explain the results you're getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the [Source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) for getting the `_source` back with only the requested fields.

Just replace the `fields` in your query with `_source` as:

```
body: {
   size: 100,
   from: 0,
   query: { match_all: {} },
   _source: ["object"]    <--- this is an object

}
```

**Here's why the results (hit counts) are different when you used the fields option:**

The `fields` parameter is about fields that are explicitly marked as stored in the mapping, which is off by default and generally not recommended.
For backwards compatibility, if the `fields` parameter specifies fields which are not stored (`store` mapping set to false), it will load the `_source` and extract it from it.

Also **only leaf fields can be returned via the field option**. So object fields can’t be returned and such requests will fail.

But if you search across multiple indices with an `object` field in the `fields` option and if this field is not present or mapped to a different datatype other than `object` (like `string` or `long`) in all or some of the indices, then such requests won't fail and will be returned in the hits array.

This is the reason why you get different values for `hits.total` and `hits.hits.length`

Output of a typical such query would look like:

```
{
  "took": 91,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 10,
    "successful": 9,
    "failed": 1,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 1,
        "index": "test_index1",
        "node": "GQN77mbqTSmmmwQlmjSBEg",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "field [object] isn't a leaf field"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 25,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test_index2",
        "_type": "test_type1",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index2",
        "_type": "test_type2",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1
      },
      {
        "_index": "test_index2",
        "_type": "test_type3",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "object": [
            "simple text"    <-- here the field 'object' is a leaf field
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here `hits.total` is the total no: of docs across all indices searched as it is a match all query.

And `hits.hits.length` is the no: of docs for which the request did not fail.

Comment: do you happen to know why using an object in 'fields' does not lead the proper result?

Comment: Edited the answer to include explanation :-)

Comment: @MrE: My apologies, there's a correction. Elasticsearch strictly allows only same mapping for fields with same name in different mapping types in the same index. Hence the field 'object' in 'test_index' cannot be at the same time 'string' and 'object'. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. i'm still a bit confused about the usefulness of 'fields' if _source does it more consistently for all types of keys. Most examples in the elastic docs use fields. i guess i need to understand what stored vs not stored means in ES. will have to do some more reading...

Comment: Here's a SO question on the same: [Stored field in elastic search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663635/stored-field-in-elastic-search). If you're not satisfied with the explanation, please feel free to ask another question and link it here, will be glad to explain.